# asp.net Razor v3 jquery ajax post returns 404 not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

I recently started a Asp.net Razor v3 project. It's the first time I use this (before I only used MVC and Web Forms)

I am struggling to get a code behind that gets called by a jquery ajax function to work. When debugging on Chrome I see that the script returns POST 404 (Not Found)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../App_Code/GlobalSitesController/GetSiteTable",
  data: "{'siteName': 'Some Site' , 'daysDiff': '0'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("siteTable").innerHTML = response.responseText;
  },
  failure: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("siteTable").innerHTML = "ERROR" + response.responseText;
  },
  error: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("siteTable").innerHTML = "ERROR" + response.responseText;
  }
});

public class GlobalSitesController : Controller
{
 [HttpPost]
 public string GetSiteTable(string siteName, int daysDiff)
 {
  return "some string";
 }
}
```

First I noticed that my project didn't include `System.Web.Mvc` so I added `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` via Nugget

The full Chrome error is jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23 POST http://localhost:9997/App_Code/GlobalSitesController/GetSiteTable 404 (Not Found). This is the correct URL and should be working

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the url bit needs to be in the following form

```
url: '@url.Action("GetSiteTable", "GlobalSitesController")',
```

(url needs to be initialised as in below)

```
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Comment: No, it needs to be `url: '@Url.Action("GetSiteTable", "GlobalSites")',` - no `"Controller"` suffix and you do not need the 2nd code snippet - its just uppercase `@Url.Action(...)`

Comment: You're right. In the end I found I was missing the routing in _AppStart